# How to set the message load balance consumption in RocketMQ with two client?

Tags: rocketmq

There are two Rocket MQ clients, both of which belong to the same consumption group. How to set the message load balance consumption? It seems that one client has more consumption messages and the other has less, and the consumption is uneven.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://github.com/apache/rocketmq/issues/4828) should clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```java
DefaultMQPushConsumer consumer = new DefaultMQPushConsumer("CID_JODIE_1");
consumer.subscribe("TopicTest", "*");

// MessageModel.CLUSTERING means all consumers consume load-balancely
// MessageModel.BROADCASTING means every consumer instance will consume all messages
consumer.setMessageModel(MessageModel.CLUSTERING);
```